# WooCommerce Cart - Dynamically set product price THEN apply coupon to new totals

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to dynamically set a product price, which I can do just fine. However when I try to apply a coupon that has a minimum spend, the coupon will not apply.

*EDIT*

The dynamic pricing updates and everything looks good, the apply_coupon just doesn't work when I have a minimum spend on the coupon. It's like it cannot see the newly calculated totals.

Anyone got any ideas?

```
$coupon_code = 'coupontest';
$cart = new WC_Cart();
$cart->add_to_cart(531, 1);

foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
    $cart_item['data']->set_price( (float) 100 );
}

$cart->calculate_totals(); //this works! the prices are calculated correctly

//Minimum spend on the coupon is not met though?
$cart->apply_coupon($coupon_code); //this does not work!
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do a var_dump on $cart after you apply the price and see if your dynamic pricing has actually been applied. Then do the same for calculate_totals() and see if that is working as expected.

Comment: Yes both being applied.

Comment: it seems the coupon is still looking at the original cart total for some reason. look through the docs and try to see what you find.

Comment: You should give the complete related code (including the dynamic price part) as your actual provided code is not enough to see what is wrong.

Comment: I update my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Nope as we don't know where you are running this code… Is it on a template, on a hooked function… so please update your answer with something more complete including the hooked function with it's hook if there is one.